# Запуск примеров из android ndk-r10b

Tags: android-ndk

Собираю проекты из Android NDK в убунту. ([ndk-r10b](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html))

Пошагово:

1. Запускаю ndk-build для конкретного примера.
2. Делаю импорт, как проект в эклипс, и запускаю на эмуляторе.
3. Вижу результат в виде запущеного приложения.

На простых примерах, как hello-jni, все работает успешно.

На других при вызове "ndk-build" получаю ошибку с текстом:

" Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk  
/home/user/android-ndk-r10b/build/core/add-application.mk:209: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop."

Где я ошибся?
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими ошибками в новой ндк?

Заранее спасибо.